# Traffic density data source

Tags: data-request, transportation

**Data:** I am looking for [traffic density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_flow#Density) for a given place, preferably averaged over a given area for the last year. Traffic density is defined as the number of vehicles per unit length of the roadway.

**Context:** We're building an non-profit application that lets a user choose a city to live based on multiple factors, including traffic density. My assumption is that critical traffic density, that leads to [traffic congestion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traffic_congestion), has impact both on commute time and quality of neighborhood. For instance, this is traffic density map from [TomTom Traffic Index](https://www.tomtom.com/en_gb/traffic-index/). I placed arrows to show cities with high, medium and low congestion at the moment:

[image: TomTom Traffic Index Example]

**Region:** This is for large and small cities and villages only in Poland, Europe.

**License:** This will be a non-profit application and we're building only a MVP, so at this stage we don't want to invest any money. Any free for non-commercial use license would be good.

**Format:** . It can be both structured (e.g. via JSON, CSV file or API) or not well-structured source. I am not afraid of screenscraping. Preferably, that should be a source we can query on regular, but not necessarily frequent basic (yearly) to update our estimates.

**Authority:** I do not have limitations here. Most of the data providers in this domain comes from anonymous GPS devices and are collected through routing applications like TomTom or Google Maps.

Answer (score 1):

This might be related to what you are looking for:

CalTrans has a release of data on the [Annual Average Daily Traffic (AADT) Volumes](https://data.ca.gov/dataset/annual-average-daily-traffic-volumes).

More information could be found [here](https://dot.ca.gov/programs/traffic-operations/census/traffic-volumes/2017).

Comment: Thank you, but this seems only for California. In gives me, however, some directions where to search.